# Angularjs Copy(), Extend() object reference issue

Tags: angularjs

I want copy object to another temp object without reference. I've tried with copy & extend.

```
angular.copy(source, destination);
angular.extend(destination, source);
```

I'm copying `mainObject` to `tempObject`. Once I copied I'm not doing anything. But whenever data is changing in `mainObject`,  `tempObject` data is also changing. I don't want any changes in `tempObject`.

Comment: I think you want `destination = angular.copy(source)`

Comment: @ExplosionPills that' one parameter . it can be done two parameter also

Comment: can your provide a plunkr/jsfiddle with dummy data that will produce your problem ?

Comment: `angular.extend` is definitely not what you want in this situation, but this sounds exactly like what `angular.copy` is made for.  Can you provide an example that verifies that something is indeed broken with the implementation of this core mechanic?